# Oracle JavaMail IMAP provider not compatible with Java 9?

Tags: jakarta-mail, imap, java-9

I get a compile error from maven when building a project under Java 9 that uses the Oracle JavaMail IMAP provider:

```
... cannot access com.sun.mail.util.ReadableMime
[ERROR]   class file for com.sun.mail.util.ReadableMime not found
```

(ReadableMime is an interface implemented by IMAPMessage)

It works under Java 8.

The dependencies are:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
  <artifactId>imap</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Neither javax.mail-api nor imap include a com.sun.mail.util package, but it seems to be no longer part (if it ever officially was) of the JRE.

So, I guess this is a bug in the Oracle imap provider that pops up now in the presence of Jigsaw, or am I missing something?

Interestingly, the Eclipse compiler doesn't complain.

Comment: *Eclipse compiler doesn't complain*.. which compiler does? I mean to say what is your configuration for `maven-compiler-plugin`?

Comment: The plugin is 3.7.0, level 1.9, Oracle JDK 9.0.1

Comment: The class is in `javax.mail-1.6.0.jar`. You're using the wrong artefact.

Comment: EJP: Thanks, that's it.

Comment: Just a additional note, you can make use of the Advanced search option on central for this as well -> https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3A%22com.sun.mail.util.ReadableMime%22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to EJP:

*com.sun.mail:imap* works with *com.sun.mail:javax.mail*, but not with j*avax.mail:javax.mail-api*.

The latter does not include the *com.sun.mail.util* package.
*com.sun.mail:imap* does not declare any Maven dependency, but de facto it has a compile dependency to *com.sun.mail:javax.mail*.

Comment: com.sun.mail:javax.mail *includes* the imap provider, as described on the [JavaMail project page](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/#Download_JavaMail_Release).  If you want only the imap provider, without the smtp or pop3 providers, you need to use com.sun.mail:mailapi with com.sun.mail:imap